# Transfer all numbers from an Array into another in Java

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I have a list that is holding multiple numbers in the same index, with all but the last number separated by a comma. I'd like to get all these numbers and transfer them to an array, but I want all individual numbers to be in different indexes in this new array. How can I achieve that? I was unable to find a problem similar to mine and have been struggling with it for a while.

I've considered that my way of collecting the data from the `data.csv` file could be considered bad and I need something completely different.

My Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String file = "data.csv";
    String line;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i = 0;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            //System.out.println(line);
            list.add(i, line);
            i++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Data.csv file:

```
20,16,23,20,2,17,9,16,0,6
20,18,16,4,10,9,4,10,16,16
3,6,19,14,14,0,5,22,4,15
19,22,6,18,9,12,15,9,25,14
20,0,1,20,6,19,20,16,15,6
13,1,6,1,4,22,3,11,1,12
10,9,20,7,21,22,3,14,1,8
25,19,21,14,15,16,25,17,6,14
0,20,10,1,3,24,24,5,10,24
2,13,0,9,18,5,21,2,24,21
17,4,16,6,22,14,15,5,10,20
6,15,10,8,10,10,16,22,15,22
2,1,3,25,15,19,0,13,7,17
24,20,6,7,3,3,12,22,23,17
12,10,10,14,2,18,21,5,21,3
13,9,20,11,8,3,23,5,5,3
4,18,4,9,1,2,24,21,23,3
3,3,2,19,6,19,1,10,5,4
13,0,12,19,24,7,10,18,18,1
0,7,10,2,22,20,21,4,3,11
```

Expected result:

```
Data[0] = 20
Data[1] = 16
Data[2] = 23
Data[10] = 20
Data[11] = 18
```

Comment: Just `list.append(…)` to append to your list and then `list.toArray(String[]::new)` to get an array. `line.split(",")` to split each input line into an array with the elements in the string delimited by a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line that you're reading still has lots of numbers that you want to add to your list individually.  Use [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to split them into an array of values.  Convert that array to a List with [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)), them add them all to your target list with the [`addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) method.

```
String line;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can always convert the `List` to an array with

```
String[] values = list.toArray(String[]::new);
```

If you'd like to use Java Streams, create a `Path`, get the lines, and for each line, `split` into an array of values, convert to a `List`, use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) to flatten the `Lists` to a stream of values, then collect to a `List`.

```
List<String> list = null;
try {
    list = Files.lines(Path.of(file))
        .map(line -> line.split(","))
        .map(Arrays::asList)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());  // or .toList();  with Java 16+
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or you can convert the `Stream` directly to an array, replacing the call to `collect` or `toList` with [`toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)):

```
String[] values = Files.lines(Path.of(file))
    .map(line -> line.split(","))
    .map(Arrays::asList)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```